# LiveValidation Trigger Form Validation But Not Submit

Tags: javascript, livevalidation

I'm using LiveValdiation to validate my form and it works great.
One problem I'm having is that I have a "View as PDF" link which saves the form and pops up the PDF in another window.
The reason why I save first before viewing the PDF is that users often don't click the Save button before previewing their PDF. They will fill out the form and click on "View as PDF" right away assuming that they can see the PDF with the fields they filled out.

If the form has fields that are required but weren't filled out, the save call fails.
I want to know whether there is a way to trigger the LiveValidation form validation when the "View as PDF" is clicked and will only proceed with the PDF part if validation passes.

I thought triggering a simple form submit would do the trick but the problem is that even though it validates, since it submits the form, the form reloads and doesn't get to execute the PDF call code. This is why I need a LiveValidation form validation which does all the live validation on the form but doesn't submit the form.
Does anyone know how to do this?